# Databinding to WrapPanel does not work as expected

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, wrappanel

I'm trying to populate a `WrapPanel` with a collection of my own user controls.

Child control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.StockMappings.StockView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Width="140" Height="80">
        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.4*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=StockName}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

cs file:

```
namespace MyApplication.StockMappings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StockView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StockView : UserControl
    {
        public StockView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string StockName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the window with the wrap panel:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.StockMappings.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication.StockMappings"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="Stocks" ItemsSource="{Binding AllStocks}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>                        
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:StockView/>                                            
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the C# code again:

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var stocks = new[]
        {
            new StockView() { ID = "M0", StockName = "abc"},
            new StockView() { ID = "M1", StockName = "def"},
        };

        Stocks.DataContext = new Test()
        {
            AllStocks = stocks.ToList()
        }; 
    }
}
```

The `Test` class (the container for child data) is very simple:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<StockView> AllStocks
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And finally, the result:

[image: screenshot]

All borders are blank. Neither `ID` nor `StockName` are displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

I have confirmed (by adding a dummy property) that `StockView` controls take the `ID` value from the `Test` object, not the children from the `AllStocks` list. But why? Have I not defined the `ItemTemplate`? What is it for, then?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` - Everything. The UI is not the right place to store Data. Create a proper Model or ViewModel to store that data and bind your controls to that. Also let the UI create the UI, don't instantiate the UI elements yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is an appropriate view model item class that holds your data. That should not be confused with the view object, e.g. your StockView.

First, remove the `ID` and `StockName` properties from the StockView control. These properties will move to the data item class.

```
public partial class StockView : UserControl
{
    public StockView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Second, create the view model with a `StockItem` data item class, and a `ViewModel` class that has the `AllStocks` property (or just call it `Test` as you already did).

```
public class StockItem
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string StockName { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<StockItem> AllStocks { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, set the DataContext of your MainWindow to an instance of the ViewModel class.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel { AllStocks = new ObservableCollection<StockItem>() };
    vm.AllStocks.Add(new StockItem { ID = "M0", StockName = "abc" });
    vm.AllStocks.Add(new StockItem { ID = "M1", StockName = "def" });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

In case the data items could be modified after being added to the `AllStocks` collection, the `StockItem` class would have to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020.aspx) interface.

Comment: All answers were useful, but I'm accepting thise one as the most comprehensive answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `DataContext` of the `StockView` usercontrol should be its own code behind class.

That should make it work!

```
public StockView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set datacontent of your usercontrol
for example in code:

```
public StockView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
```

Comment: I see Peter was faster :-)

Answer (score 1):

`DataTemplates` template data, you bind to a list of controls, the `ItemTemplate` will be ignored as the controls can be added directly, you should get a warning about this in you output. Because of this no `DataContext` is set for the `UserControls`, you should move the properties from the `UserControl` to a model class and add instances of that. Also i would advise against setting the `DataContext` of your `UserControl`.